# mongo use $lookup after $group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a visits collection where I successfully count the number of visits per location

Visits model:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a3969e2f4ea3e33ac5a523d"
    },
    "locationId": "5a395ccf210a1d35d0df4a58"
}
```

locationId above is of type 'Object' as I learned lookup localField and foreignField must be of same type

nodejs code =>

```
let sort = { "count": -1, "locationId": 1 };

Visit.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{ 
            $and: [
                { accountId: req.session.passport.user }, 
                { 
                    'details.dateTimeIn': { 
                        $gte: new Date(dateFrom), $lte: new Date(dateTo) 
                    } 
                }
            ] 
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            //_id: name,
            _id: "$locationId",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    { $sort: sort }
])
```

Output is half ok:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"5a395ccf210a1d35d0df4a58",
      "count":20
   }
]
```

Instead of showing location id id like to show location name. Schema for locations collection is:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a395ccf210a1d35d0df4a58"
        "name": "Tower A",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Research suggests I need to use $lookup to get that JOIN effect

So I tried

```
{
    "$lookup": {
        from: "locations",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "locationdetails"
     }
}
```

but the match seems broken. The closest I got was a list of all locations in 'locationdetails'

But with code above here is the empty locationdetails

```
[
   {
      "_id":"5a395ddf1d221918d0041313",
      "count":20,
      "locationdetails":[

      ]
   }
]
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: This will [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093647/mongodb-join-on-id-field-from-string-to-objectid).

Comment: Hmm I flipped all all the foreign fields to type Object from String. Doesn't seem to help.