# How to use ObjectId in $lookup using mongodb nodejs drivers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-lookup

Please help me to find out a suitable solution

collection were users details are stored **app_users**

```
{
  _id: {
    $oid: "abcd1235a6ad4a56dadasd"
  },
  user_name: "vikas Kandari",
  user_dp: "ASDAD486412.jpg"
}
```

collection where users bookings are stored **bookings**

```
{
  _id : {
    $oid : "asdasdasdasdasd"
  },
  user_id : "abcd1235a6ad4a56dadasd",
  booking_item : "some product",
  booking_date : "datetime"
}
```

Lookup(left Join) query i am using is

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const url = 'mongodb://root:root@localhost:3000/app';
const dbName = 'app';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(err, null);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('users');
  collection.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'bookings',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'user_id',
      as: 'bookings'
    }
  }]).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log(docs);
  });
  client.close();
});
```

I want to select bookings with there corresponding user details from users collections but Its returning blank because mongodb is comparing string with objectId so is there any way to perform this task ?

Comment: So according to this open [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22781) it's not implemented yet

Comment: But they have released 3+ version of drivers

Comment: its a really frustrating issue

Comment: What is your schema?

Comment: i have basically Two Collections

Comment: users and bookings i want to select bookings with corresponding user details like user_name and user_dp

Comment: update your question with your schema detail. So ppl can figure out something you can do to fix your problem. It's easier with the actual code

Comment: convert userId string to Object using [toObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093647/mongodb-join-on-id-field-from-string-to-objectid)

Answer (score 0):

Add This before the lookup

```
$project:{
    $let:
        {
         vars: { id:'_id.$oid' },
         in: ObjectId("$$id")
         }
}
```

Change to

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'bookings',
  localField: '_id.$oid',
  foreignField: 'user_id',
  as: 'bookings'
}
```

Comment: actually i just modified my functions and i put a extra __id field which is text