# How to join in mongo query with Array of IDs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

> Below is my TEST table object which contains category id array

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ede075651957a5d540c7828"),
    "Tags" : [ 
        "demo", 
        "skype"
    ],
    "CategoryID" : [ 
        "5edb65a834c5cc735a76b8e4", 
        "5edb65ae34c5cc735a76b8e5"
    ],
    "Title" : "demo 1",
    "Description" : "<p>sdfsdf</p>",
    "MetaTitle" : "asd",
    "MetaDescription" : "asdas",
    "MetaKeywords" : "asd",
    "CanonicalUrl" : "asd",
    "Index" : "No Index",
    "ImagePath" : "",
    "Position" : 0,
    "AuthorID" : ObjectId("5ecbae9f1bfe823e940e12a0"),
    "AuthorName" : "Admin",
    "SearchTerm" : "",
    "isPublish" : "0",
    "isDeleted" : false,
    "AddedOn" : ISODate("2020-06-08T09:39:34.007Z"),
    "LastModifiedOn" : ISODate("2020-06-08T09:39:34.007Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

> Below is my category table from which I want to fetch category name

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5edb65a834c5cc735a76b8e4"),
    "Name" : "Cat 1",
    "ParentID" : "0",
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "AddedOn" : ISODate("2020-06-06T09:45:12.632Z"),
    "LastModifiedOn" : ISODate("2020-06-06T09:45:12.632Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

So, I want to get the records from "TEST" table also want to join with the "Category" Table to get the comma separated **Category name** which are in "TEST" Table in Array format.

> I tried below query, but it is working for only when there is single
>   record in "CategoryID" array. And if I send multiple records in categoryID array, then it gives same record multiple times with different category.

```
const getData = await TESTModel.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Category",       // other table name (Admin Table)
            localField: "CategoryID",   // name of blog table field
            foreignField: "_id", // name of Admin table field
            as: "testdata"         // alias for userinfo table
        },
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$testdata",
        $unwind: {
            path: "$testdata",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
])
```

So, how can I get the Comma separated Category name in the query result.

Comment: The fields you are trying to "join" with in the `category` and `TEST` collection are to be of same data type (one of them is ObjectId and another is a String in an array). They need to be of same type. You can use aggregation operator [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/index.html) to convert ObjectId to String and then compare. `$lookup` has a [variation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) where you can specify a _pipeline_  for matching  (with conversion).

Comment: Thanks, Can you give me an example in answer?

Comment: You may want to try and tell what problem you are facing. The lookup's pipeline allows using `$match` stage in which you can compare the String array with the String version of the ObjectId. There are examples in the provided links. See this post: [Mongodb Join on _id field from String to ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093647/mongodb-join-on-id-field-from-string-to-objectid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below code.

```
const data = TESTModel.aggregate([
       {
           $lookup:{
             from: "blogCategory",
             localField: "CategoryID",
             foreignField: "_id",
             as: "enrollee_info"
          }
       }
])
```