# Mongodb lookup query when foreign field is an array

Tags: javascript, database, typescript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have these 2 collections in MongoDb:

User

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId("xxxxxxxxx"),
  roleId: ObjectId: ("xxxxxxxxx)
}
```

Courses

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId("xxxxxxxxx"),
  name: "Course 1",
  relationRoleCourses: [
    {
      userRoleId: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
      userRoleId: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm looking for a query using lookup to get all users with their corresponding courses where the course must include the role of the user.

Expected Result

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId("xxxxxxxxx"),
  roleId: ObjectId: ("xxxxxxxxx),
  courses: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId("xxxxxxxxx"),
      name: "Course 1",
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId("xxxxxxxxx"),
      name: "Course 2",
    }
  ],
}
```

Considerations:

- In the relationRoleCourses array the userRoleId is a string, not an ObjectId.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "courses",
      localField: "roleId",
      foreignField: "relationRoleCourses.userRoleId",
      as: "courses"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Not working, courses are empty in the result

Comment: That’s because of string stored roleId, check this https://mongoplayground.net/p/hL21XKr3F-B and this, it depends also on the mongo version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093647/mongodb-join-on-id-field-from-string-to-objectid#comment108271411_41095024